# Load images from an array with jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, image, preload

I have an array of numerical values and, using jQuery, would like to preload images based on that array. For example, if the array is `["1", "5", "8", "23"]`, I'd like to preload the following images:

```
/images/1.jpg
/images/5.jpg
/images/8.jpg
/images/23.jpg
```

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Source](http://engineeredweb.com/blog/09/12/preloading-images-jquery-and-javascript)

```
var cache = [];
var imgArray=  new Array("1", "2", "3");
var prefix= "/images/";
var suffix = ".jpg";

function Preload(arrayName){
    var args_len = arrayName.length;
    for (var i = args_len; i--;) 
    {
        var cacheImage = document.createElement('img');
        cacheImage.src = prefix + arrayName[i] + suffix;
        cache.push(cacheImage);
    }
}

//usage
Preload(imgArray);
```